# Properly format SQL query when insert into variable number of columns

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using `psycopg2` to interact with a `PostgreSQL` database. I have a function whereby any number of columns (from a single column to all columns) in a table could be inserted into. My question is: *how would one properly, dynamically, construct this query?*

At the moment I am using string formatting and concatenation and I know this is the absolute ***worst*** way to do this. Consider the below code where, in this case, my unknown number of columns (i.e. keys from a `dict` is in fact 2):

```
dictOfUnknownLength = {'key1': 3, 'key2': 'myString'}

def createMyQuery(user_ids, dictOfUnknownLength):
    fields, values = list(), list()

    for key, val in dictOfUnknownLength.items():
        fields.append(key)
        values.append(val)

    fields = str(fields).replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')').replace("'", "")
    values = str(values).replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')')

    query = f"INSERT INTO myTable {fields} VALUES {values} RETURNING someValue;"
```

> `query = INSERT INTO myTable (key1, key2) VALUES (3, 'myString') RETURNING someValue;`

This provides a correctly formatted query but is of course prone to SQL injections and the like and, as such, is not an acceptable method of achieving my goal.

In other queries I am using the [recommended](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) methods of query construction when handling a known number of variables (`%s` and separate argument to `.execute()` containing variables) but I'm unsure how to adapt this to accommodate an unknown number of variables without using string formatting.

How can I elegantly and *safely* construct a query with an unknown number of specified insert columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to your worries, the current methodology using `.replace()` is prone to edge cases where fields or values contain `[`, `]`, or `'`. They will get replaced *no matter what* and may mess up your query.

You could always use `.join()` to join a *variable* number of values in your list. To top it up, [format](https://pyformat.info/) the query appropriately with `%s` after `VALUES` and pass your arguments into `.execute()`.

*Note: You may also want to consider the case where the number of fields is not equal to the number values.*

```
import psycopg2


conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")
cur = conn.cursor()

dictOfUnknownLength = {'key1': 3, 'key2': 'myString'}


def createMyQuery(user_ids, dictOfUnknownLength):
    # Directly assign keys/values.
    fields, values = list(dictOfUnknownLength.keys()), list(dictOfUnknownLength.values())

    if len(fields) != len(values):
        # Raise an error? SQL won't work in this case anyways...
        pass

    # Stringify the fields and values.
    fieldsParam = ','.join(fields) # "key1, key2"
    valuesParam = ','.join(['%s']*len(values))) # "%s, %s"

    # "INSERT ... (key1, key2) VALUES (%s, %s) ..."
    query = 'INSERT INTO myTable ({}) VALUES ({}) RETURNING someValue;'.format(fieldsParam, valuesParam)

    # .execute('INSERT ... (key1, key2) VALUES (%s, %s) ...', [3, 'myString'])
    cur.execute(query, values) # Anti-SQL-injection: pass placeholder
                               # values as second argument.
```

Comment: I believe this approach will lead to column names being treated as strings and thus encapsulated within `' '` and therefore being invalid SQL syntax?

Comment: Ensuring that `len(fields)==len(values)` is a very good point, thanks.