When reading data into a sqlite database using a formatted statement, I can generate what looks to be a proper statement, but it won't execute
This is a web application I intend to submit as the final project in the cs50 online programming course, using:

python
sqlite
flask

The goal of the project is to provide on-the-fly grading capability to my faculty (I teach an unrelated course): The faculty log into the application, select which student team they wish to grade, are shown images of the students in that team and have a form via which to submit grades. The input and output are csv spreadsheets.
To make implementation easier (I hoped), I'm using the SQL object provided by that class:
https://github.com/cs50/python-cs50/blob/main/src/cs50/sql.py
The nature of this SQL object is that it won't interact directly with pandas; dataframe.to_sql won't run. Checking the source code, it appears that the necessary sql functionality isn't present in the SQL object.  Thus, I am manually iterating over each row of the csv.
Each session's grades generate four columns: attendence, preparation, participation, and result; the column names are prepended to the lab session (e.g. attendence_lab_1). Once a faculty member submits grades, the data is read back to a temporary csv file, then the temp file is renamed with the name of the original csv, overwriting it.  For the next grading session, I recreate the database by reading in from the csv.  This means that I can't hardcode my column headers; I need to read the headers from the csv, generate a list from that, then create an INSET INTO statement from that list of headers.  Using the answers at Python sqlite3, create table columns from a list with help of .format as a model, I've been able to get my headers into the table.  But when I iterate over the rows I get errors:

Statements must be separated by newlines or semicolons
String literal is unterminated

I think I understand what these types of errors are, in a general sense, but I'm not understanding how I'm generating them.
The code:
# https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/io.html
df = pd.read_csv(stpath, header=0)
#df.to_sql(students, con)
headers = df.columns.values.tolist() # draw list of headers from df

# create table via prepared statement that scales with number of columns in table
def createTableStatement(tableName, columnList):
    return f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {tableName} (id INTEGER, {columnList[0]}" + (", {}"*(len(columnList)-1)).format(*(columnList[1:])) + ", PRIMARY KEY(id))"
db.execute(createTableStatement("students", headers))

# read data into table
def createRowStatement(columnList):
    return f'"INSERT INTO students ({columnList[0]}' + (', {}'*(len(columnList)-1)).format(*(columnList[1:])) + ') VALUES (?' + (', ?'*(len(columnList)-1)) + ')", row["Student"]' + (', row["{}"]'*(len(columnList)-1)).format(*(columnList[1:])) + ')'


with open(stpath, "r", encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        x = createRowStatement(headers)
        print(x)
        db.execute(x)

An earlier version of the code substituted {columnList[0]} for row["Student"]' in the INSERT INTO statement. This resulted in the generated sql query:
"INSERT INTO students (Student, Team, Session, Pod, Image, Lab1_Grade, Lab1_attend, Lab1_prep, Lab1_part, Lab1_disect) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", {columnList[0]}, row["Team"], row["Session"], row["Pod"], row["Image"], row["Lab1_Grade"], row["Lab1_attend"], row["Lab1_prep"], row["Lab1_part"], row["Lab1_disect"])

Changing {columnList[0]} to row["Student"]' generated the appropriate list of headers:
"INSERT INTO students (Student, Team, Session, Pod, Image, Lab1_Grade, Lab1_attend, Lab1_prep, Lab1_part, Lab1_disect) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", row["Student"], row["Team"], row["Session"], row["Pod"], row["Image"], row["Lab1_Grade"], row["Lab1_attend"], row["Lab1_prep"], row["Lab1_part"], row["Lab1_disect"])

I suspect the error is somehow related to this behavior - am I missing a quotation mark?  Did I put in too many?  Is the line of code simply too long (how should I break it up?)?

But when I iterate over the rows I get errors Show us the actual errors.  Don't make us guess.

@JohnGordon They gave the errors in the bullet items. They're coming from the CS50 grading system, not from Python.

You shouldn't have double quotes inside single quotes.

@Barmar.  As these are from his final project, these would be Python / SQL errors, not CS50 Grading system errors

Why doesn't the for loop use row anywhere?

@Barmar: how did you add those horizontal scrollbars?

@JohnGordon: the errors are in the bullet points, these are the errors as listed in my IDE (Visual Studio)

@Badger273 By putting the code inside triple backtick code fences.

@Barmar: my intent was for the for statement to use the createRowStatement for each row - I was trying to shorten the line of code a bit, but perhaps I dropped something along the way

@barmar I also tried it with the double quotes on the outside, single on the inside, and had a similar error - I'll try it again to get the specifics

@Badger  As for your secondary question as the end, the issue is that {columnList[0]} outside of an f-string is creating a set containing the value of columnList[0].
I'm working on a solution but still working on parsing out the use of .format
The use of f-strings and format here is potentially dangerous due to SQL injection possibilities.  You should instead be adding ? for each needed column and passing the values as a tuple.

So if the code has basic python syntax errors, the cs50 grader does not show the full error traceback message?  That's not so great.

If these are basic python syntax errors, which it sounds like they are, you might get better error feedback by just running the code yourself in python directly, instead of using the cs50 grader.  Then, once you have solved the syntax errors, you can use the grader.

Swapping the quotes to put the double-quotes on the outside gave more errors:  multiple "Statements must be separated by newlines or semicolons," "Expected attribute after '.'," "Expected expression".  IIRC, sqlite is expecting double-quotes for column titles

I'm not running the code in the c;ass environment.  I'm running it in Visual Studio.  I imported part of the class module to get the SQL object.

@nigh_anxiety - yes, I want to avoid injection.  The initial csv is the source of the headers; it's stored in a subdirectory near the application file.  Everywhere else, I'm using ? for my queries, but I couldn't figure out how to do so here, with a list of headers that is variable.  I also figured, perhaps incorrectly, that if a threat actor can get to my csv, I'm toast anyway.

@Badger273.  Can you clarify the contents of columnList with an example?  I suspect at least part of the problem is that you aren't wrapping the values in quotation marks as you format the SQL statements, so if a column header or value has a space like "First Name", it makes the SQL statement invalid.  Also, you aren't specifying data types in your CREATE TABLE statement.

@nigh_anxiety - yes, the two (very long) horizontal scrolls in my initial post are the debugging output of the problem code: I create the query in function CreateRowStatement, print the output of that function (print(x)), then attempt to run it.  Columns are Student, Team, Session, Pod, Image, etc.  The initial columns are unchanging, which enabled me to hard-code "Student", but later columns are variable, being added as the class progresses

@nigh_anxiety - I wanted to specify the datatypes in my CREATE TABLE, and originally I did, having hardcoded the whole statement.  Once I got everything to work, I realized that once I added new columns for that day's grades and read the results back to the csv file, I now needed to recreate the database - my concern is that the class we're grading has 24 sessions, over several months; I didn't want to leave all of the data in memory over that time and only output everything at the end (also, I want to see the data after every session).  I'm open to alternate implementations, though

If you are going to use pandas to read the CSV then use it to write to your database as well df.to_sql(table_name, conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

@JonSG: the SQL object doesn't recognize the needed sql commands that df.to_sql uses, unfortunately

F-strings and string.format() generally should not be used to generate SQL statements, as it potentially opens you to SQL injection attacks if there were some malformed or malicious column headers or data.
While you trust the source of the input (for now), it's something that should be avoided.  The combination of both makes these statements very difficult to parse and debug as well.
However, it is okay to use f-strings or string concatenation to insert the correct number of ? placeholders.
An additional problem I found while debugging your code is that the createRowStatement function had mismatched " and ' characters, which was probably causing  your "string literal is unterminated" error.
I also suspect there could have been problems if any of your data included spaces in the header or value, as the way you were constucting the statements did not wrap any of the inserted values in quotation marks.
Here's a possible solution. Note that I added a placeholder for the tablename in the createRowStatement function so it can be more versatile.
Also, by creating the statement with placeholders, it can now be called once before the loop, instead of having to generate a new statement for every row.
# https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/io.html
df = pd.read_csv(stpath, header=0)
#df.to_sql(students, con)
headers = df.columns.values.tolist() # draw list of headers from df

# create table via prepared statement that scales with number of columns in table
def createTableStatement(tableName, columnList):
    column_placeholders = "? TEXT, " * (len(columnList))
    statement = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ? (id INTEGER, {column_placeholders} PRIMARY KEY(id))"
    return statement, (tableName, *columnList)

statement, values = createTableStatement("students", headers)   
db.execute(statement, *values)   
# Note for anyone not familiar with CS50, the SQL library being used here expects all of the values to be passed as *args, not as a tuple like some of the built-in libraries.

# read data into table
def createRowStatement(columnList)
    column_placeholders = "?" + ", ?" * (len(columnList)-1)
    statement = f"INSERT INTO ? ({column_placeholders}) VALUES ({column_placeholders})"
    return statement


with open(stpath, "r", encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    statement = createRowStatement(headers)
    for row in reader:
        db.execute(statement, "students", *headers, *row.values())

Example outputs from these versions:
tableName="Students"
headers = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Grade", "Age"]

statement, values = createTableStatement("students", headers)   
# statement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ? (id INTEGER, ? TEXT, ? TEXT, ? TEXT, ? TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id))"
# values = ('Students', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Grade', 'Age')

statement = createRowStatement(headers)
# statement = "INSERT INTO ? (?, ?, ?, ?) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"

We can actually drop pandas entirely if you're not using it for anything else, and get the headers from the DictReader.fieldnames property.
import csv
#import pandas as pd
from cs50 import SQL


db = SQL("sqlite:///so.db")
stpath = "so.csv"
TABLENAME = "students"

# create table via prepared statement that scales with number of columns in table
def createTableStatement(tableName, columnList):
    column_placeholders = "? TEXT, " * (len(columnList))
    statement = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ? (id INTEGER, {column_placeholders} PRIMARY KEY(id))"
    return statement, (tableName, *columnList)

# read data into table
def createRowStatement(columnList):
    column_placeholders = "?" + ", ?" * (len(columnList)-1)
    statement = f"INSERT INTO ? ({column_placeholders}) VALUES ({column_placeholders})"
    return statement

with open(stpath, "r", encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    headers = reader.fieldnames
    create_statement, values = createTableStatement(TABLENAME, headers)
    db.execute(create_statement, *values)

    insert_statement = createRowStatement(headers)
    for row in reader:
        db.execute(insert_statement, TABLENAME, *headers, *row.values())

data = db.execute("SELECT * FROM ?", TABLENAME)
for row in data:
    print(row)



working through this (to understand it): in the createTableStatement function, you've added arguments on the return; so that the tableName variable substitutes into the statement at the ?, and *columnList iterates over the list of columns in columnList?  In createRowStatement, we iterate over the column_placeholders twice, generating the appropriate number of ?-marks; and since we iterate over the same "list", we automatically substitute in the same appropriate vaules at run time (example, the first ? in each run of ? might get "student", the second for each, "team,", etc?

This is generating a table where each cell bears the name of its column header: db: [{'id': 1, 'Student': 'Student', 'Team': 'Team', 'Session': 'Session', 'Pod': 'Pod', 'Image': 'Image', 'Lab1_Grade': 'Lab1_Grade', 'Lab1_attend': 'Lab1_attend', 'Lab1_prep': 'Lab1_prep', 'Lab1_part': 'Lab1_part', 'Lab1_disect': 'Lab1_disect'}, {'id': 2, 'Student': 'Student', 'Team': 'Team', 'Session': 'Session', 'Pod': 'Pod', 'Image': 'Image', 'Lab1_Grade': 'Lab1_Grade', 'Lab1_atten ...

To answer your question in the first comment, *columnList is unpacking the columnList (i.e, the header names) and spreading them into a tuple combined with tablename. So if you have tableName="students" and columnList' = ["A", "B", "C", "D"], then (tablename, *columnList) == ("students", "A", "B", "C", "D")

I hate to say this, but I'm starting to wonder if I should create a new INSERT statement for each column of each row: for row in reader/for column in headers.  That just feels very inefficient

You would actually need to use UPDATE for every  column after the first and pass in the row ID.  It would be very inefficient..  I'm investigating the problem you reported with cells being set to the wrong values now.  I need to create my own CSV for testing. What should be happening is that "student" populates the first ?, the *headers unpacks the column headers into the first (?, ?, ?, ?) and then *row should be unpacking the values into the second (?, ?, ?, ?)

Just figured out my mistake.  Because of the user of DictReader,  *row defaults to unpacking the keys, so we have to use *row.values() to get the values.  My original version works for the default csv reader.
By using DictReader, you can also get the headers from reader.fieldNames, and just handle table creation at the same time as filing the data.  I will edit the above

ok.  For other, future readers, I found the following discussion, as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502479/properly-format-sql-query-when-insert-into-variable-number-of-columns
